# Javascript loop + Object Issue: How to get required item in object with loop

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I am facing some trouble with loops, objects

I have json like this;

```
var jsonPermission = {"permissions": [
                            {"permissionId": 1, "permissionName": "Admin Permission", "roleDesc": "This is an Admin Permission"},
                            {"permissionId": 2, "permissionName": "Manager Permission", "roleDesc": "This is a Manager Permission"},
                            {"permissionId": 3, "permissionName": "User Permission", "roleDesc": "This is a user Permission"}
                        ]
                    };
```

And I have to make object like this;

```
[
    { data: "Admin Permission",        type: ["permission"] },
    { data: "Manager Permission",        type: ["permission"] },
    { data: "User Permission",      type: ["permission"] }
]
```

So I used following code;

```
//For Permissions
var permissions_len = jsonPermission.permissions.length;
var arr_permissions = [];
var permission_type = ["permission"];
for(var i=0;i<permissions_len;i++){
    var obj_permissions = {};
    obj_permissions["data"] = jsonPermission.permissions[i].permissionName;
    obj_permissions["type"] = permission_type;
    arr_permissions.push(obj_permissions);
}
```

But instead I am getting like this:

```
[
    { data: "Admin Permission",        type: [1] },
    { data: "Manager Permission",        type: [1] },
    { data: "User Permission",      type: [1] }
]
```

How to perform?

Comment: Just as a note as I can not spot an obvious error in your code: You are assigning the same array-object to all of your `type`-definitions. So in case you change this array, e.g., by appending an element, this change will affect _all_ `type` properties. I think it would be better to create a separate array for each entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
obj_permissions["type"] = [ permission_type[0] ];
```

instead of:

```
obj_permissions["type"] = permission_type;
```

See the difference?  You're working with arrays.

*[EDIT: actually there isn't much difference, but this still clarifies.  See comments.]*

Comment: I used as you suggested, but the issue remains exactly same.

Comment: hmm...I'm a little baffled by that.  If I do `var ray = ["okay"];var obj = { "x" = [ray[0]] }; console.log(obj)` I get `{ x: [ 'okay' ] }`.  To be honest, I get the same thing for your version...perhaps your problem lies somewhere else? *[Ah: apparently so -- the firefox console; I tested with `node` command line interpreter, you should get one ;)]*

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a problem of the tool you are using to evaluate the result, if you log the result to console using firefox console.log() it will give you the result as you have shown. But if you properly inspect the value using for loop in your code you can find that the values are correct.

Inspect the values as shown below

```
var permissions_len = jsonPermission.permissions.length;
var arr_permissions = [];
var permission_type = ["permission"];
for(var i=0;i<permissions_len;i++){
    var obj_permissions = {};
    obj_permissions["data"] = jsonPermission.permissions[i].permissionName;
    obj_permissions["type"] = permission_type;
    arr_permissions.push(obj_permissions);
}

for(var i=0;i<permissions_len;i++){
    var a = arr_permissions[i];
    console.log(a.data, a.type)
}
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qHatn/).

Comment: Thank you. You were right about the firefox console. And your solution shows exact values.

Answer (score 1):

Since `permission_type` is an array literal, the `type` properties of the final array items end up being arrays of one element. If you did not intend that, remove the array notation.

For example:

```
var source = jsonPermission.permissions;
var arr_permissions = [];
for(var i=0;i<source.length;i++){
    arr_permissions.push({
        data: source[i].permissionName,
        type: ["permission"] // or type: "permission" if you didn't want an array
    });
}
```

This version of the code has been simplified a bit, but also has a very important difference: each item's `type` is *not the same object anymore*, so you cannot change all of them at once (either intentionally or accidentally, which has the bad habit of occurring when you don't expect it).